# Firebase dynamic links long version not firing automatic analytics events

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

The long version of a Firebase Dynamic Link is not firing the events First-opens, clicks, re-opens...

Is that a bug or is it on purpose, and in that case why?

Background:

I cannot use the short version because I am adding programmatically a parameter in the deep link associated, hence I need the long version to accomplish it.

As a work around: how can I add programmatically a url parameter in a short Firebase dynamic link? I don't want to generate programmatically a link, I want to have only one link which has dynamic value on it (e.g. productID for a link in my product detail page)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Need your actual dynamic link to investigate this.

At the same time I can suggest that you can create short link programmatically. See [iOS docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create), [Android docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create) and [overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links).

EDIT:
When you say analytics what of the following you are referring to:

1. Data shown in Firebase Analytics (accessible from Firebase Console
   in Analytics section);
2. Data shown in Dynamic Links Analytics (accessible from Firebase Console in Dynamic Links section);
3. Data shown when in list of created dynamic links you clicking on specific link;
4. Data retrieved using [Firebase Dynamic Links Analytics API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics);

I feel that we should account long links clicks in 1 and 2. I did not get yet confirmation from server side folks to be sure about this. I would trust Ian's comment for now.

In 3 will be shown only short links created in Firebase console. Short links created using API will not show up in 3.

In 4 you can access data related to short links.

Comment: can you confirm from google perspective that this should work fine? if you use directly a long version of dynamic link instead of the short version, it will fire the automatic events?

Comment: Long links dont fire the analytics - it'll need to be a shortlink

Comment: Oleksiy thanks for your EDIT.
What it doesn't work is point 2. That's my objective, have analytics data related to each dynamic link separately. 
In case of point 1, I see some counter increasing but I cannot see for which particular dynamic link this counter is logged.